# How do I get the current date in ISO format using Perl?

Tags: perl, date

What's the most efficient way to get the current date in ISO format (e.g. "2010-10-06") using Perl?

Comment: Why are you worried about efficiency? Has your profiler told you that this section of your code is a hotspot?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most efficient for you or the computer?

For you:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime), "\n";
```

For the Computer:

```
my @t = localtime;
$t[5] += 1900;
$t[4]++;

printf "%04d-%02d-%02d", @t[5,4,3];
```

Answer (score 15):

Or you can use the DateTime module which seems to be the de facto standard date handling module these days. Need to install it from CPAN.

```
use DateTime;
my $now = DateTime->now->ymd;
```

Comment: standardizing on DateTime certainly makes things simpler for this programmer, and consistently using one fairly comprehensive module for everything seems a good idea in an area with many gotchas and inconsistencies such as date and time calculations

Comment: Use `DateTime->now->iso8601` if you want the time included as well.

Answer (score 11):

There are plenty of modules in the `Date::` namespace, many of which can help you do what you need.  Or, you can just roll your own:

```
my ($day, $mon, $year) = (localtime)[3..5];
printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", 1900+$year, 1+$mon, $day;
```

**Resources**

- Date:: namespace on The CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Date%3A%3A&mode=module

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module (bundled with Perl 5.10 and up, or you can download from CPAN), as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $today = localtime->ymd();        # Local time zone
my $todayUtc = gmtime->ymd();        # UTC
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't create any temporary variables:

```
printf "%d-%02d-%02d", map { $$_[5]+1900, $$_[4]+1, $$_[3] } [localtime];
```

Comment: Huh, I had never considered that use for map before.  I don't know if I like it, but it is certainly clever.

Comment: This kind of code is why I simultaneously love and hate perl